# question about module import error of cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I am new to Swift and Xcode, I once import Alamofire, SwiftyJSON using cocoa pods in some tutorials, In the beginning, everything works fine, but recently every time I restart my swift project, I always get an error of `No such module 'Alamofire'`, and the pods_proejctname.framework in Frameworks is lost but I didn't do anything:
[image]
However, the files in Pods in Xcode repositories doesn't show complete files and folder as finder shows:
[image]
If I opened the pods XCode project, the files in the products folder is missing, but I didn't do anything:
[image]
When I tried to fix it, this error somehow disappears. Can someone help me with this problem? please comment on my post if you need me to show further information about my project. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have lost path to your libraries in your project. Instead of configuring your path manually just remove your project from cocoa-pods and configure it again. Run the following commands on your project from the terminal

**step 1**

```
 pod deintegrate
```

**step 2:**
delete Podfile.lock and yourproject.xcworkspace file manually from your project. also if delete the pods folder from your project if exist.

**Step 3:**
install pods again by running

```
pod install
```